# Nine consecutive integers can't be partitioned into two sets such that the product of the numbers in each set equals one another?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I've been trying to answer the following problem:

> [image]

And the answer is this:

> [image]

When I was trying to answer, I understood that the prime factorization of such number could only contain $2,3,5,7$. What I don't understand is the following: When he looks at repeated prime factors, he looks at $2^2,3^2,5^2,7^2$, why didn't he look for higher powers such as $2^3,2^4$ for example?

Comment: Because numbers that are divisible by higher powers are divisible by those squares. When they talk about numbers divisible by $4$, for example, they don't mean that $2^2$ is the largest power of $2$ that divides them.

Comment: @OscarRascal I think I get it. I don't understand how he comes up with the conclusion that at most $3$ of them are divisible by $4$. The reason given previously doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: $4k, 4k+4, 4k+8$. The distance between $4k+8$ and $4k$ is already $8$. The next multiple of $4$ would be $4k+12$, which is at distance $12$ from $4k$. It doesn't fit inside $9$ consecutive numbers.

Comment: @OscarRascal: That's an answer; you should put it as an answer, not a comment.